# A common ICommonService pattern for multiple Domain objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm writing up the Data layer of server-side blazor SPA (one project only) and I'm following a sample where the teacher plays with a single domain object: an Employee. So he has a class `EmployeeService` to be injected and this class implements `IEmployeeService`. In my case, I have a few more such classes:

```
public interface IDesignManagerService
{
    Task<List<DesignManager>> GetDesignManagers();
    Task<bool> CreateDesignManager(DesignManager newStage);
    Task<bool> EditDesignManager(byte id, DesignManager modifiedDesignManager);
    Task<DesignManager> SingleDesignManager(byte id);
    Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(byte id);
}

public interface IFundedService
{
    Task<List<Funded>> GetFunded();
    Task<bool> CreateFunded(Funded newStage);
    Task<bool> EditFunded(byte id, Funded modifiedFunded);
    Task<Funded> SingleFunded(byte id);
    Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(byte id);
}

public interface IGateService
{
    Task<List<Gate>> GetGates();
    Task<bool> CreateGate(Gate newStage);
    Task<bool> EditGate(byte id, Gate modifiedGate);
    Task<Gate> SingleGate(byte id);
    Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(byte id);
}
```

Immediately, I feel like there should be a common interface having the basic methods so I can somehow use the dynamic type like `Create<Employee>` or `Create<Gate>`. Can this be accomplished here? I know what I might want but am unable to dig for help due to a lack of familiarity with the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has already provide a sample for this pattern. See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/modern-web-applications-characteristics) and [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb).

To answer your question it self, you need a [**generic `IAsyncRepository`**](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/blob/3e228035c071ec6e0406f73a7ef6dc0dc303c84e/src/ApplicationCore/Interfaces/IAsyncRepository.cs#L7-L16) as the common interface:

```cs
// an empty marker interface
public interface IAggregateRoot{ }

// a common entity that has an `Id` property
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
}

// the common Repo interface
public interface IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync();
    Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAsync(ISpecification<T> spec);
    Task<T> AddAsync(T entity);
    Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task DeleteAsync(T entity);
    Task<int> CountAsync(ISpecification<T> spec);
}
```

And then make your specific repo service inherit the `IRepository<T>`. For example, your `IGateRepository` can be refactored as:

```
public class Gate: BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    // Add Gate props here
}


public interface IGateService : IAsyncRepository<Gate>
{
    // add more interface methods if you want
}
```

By this way, you can invoke the service with generic types inference:

```
await gateSvc.AddAsync(gate);
await fundedSvc.AddAsync(funded);
...
```

Comment: And in the Blazor app, this can be added as IoC (Each service)?

Comment: @HassanGulzar Blazor Server app is a plain ASP.NET Core project + Blazor. So of course you can make use DI like `services.AddScoped<IGateService, MyGateService>(); services.AddScoped<IFundedService, MyFundedService()>`.